# @RequestParam(required = false) doesn't seem to work anymore in spring-boot 3.0

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi, springdoc

I've updated lately my spring-boot stack from 2.x to 3.x and I've noticed that even if I set @RequestParam(required = false), the swagger UI shows the request param as required.

This was not the case on 2.x stack

I use:

```
springboot 3.0.4
swagger-annotations: 1.6.10
springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui: 2.0.4
```

My controller looks like this:

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/code", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public SearchResultDTO searchByCode(@RequestParam(required = true) String code, @RequestParam(required = false) String locale,
            @RequestParam(required = false) Double latitude, @RequestParam(required = false) Double longitude,
            @RequestParam(required = false) Double distanceInKm) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
        return searchService.searchProductByCode(code, locale, latitude, longitude, distanceInKm);
    }
```

For this controller definition, my swagger page looks like this:

[image]

Any idea what is causing this behavior?

Thanks

Comment: Your post title is misleading. Swagger doesn’t work isn’t the same thing as the annotation not working.

Comment: Didn't reproduce on my local.
Could you create a repository to reproduce it?

Comment: Same happens to me.

Comment: best: don't depend on `swagger-annotations: 1.6.10` , but only (transitively via) `springdoc-openapi-starter-[webmvc|webflux]-ui` ..which (currently) depends on: `io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations-jakarta`

Comment: I've removed swagger-annotations from my dependencies, but  I am still seeing the same behavior.

Comment: When I will get some time to spear, I will try to download the openapi source code and do some debugging locally, to hopefully see what is causing this behavior.

Comment: Due to official document, https://springdoc.org/#why-my-parameter-is-marked-as-required. It's look like there are no way to prevent appearing "required".   


However, I found the way. It's simple.  
**Just use 2 annotations.**     


i.e)  
`@RequestParam(required = false) @Parameter(requried = false) Double latitude`    

hope this will work!

Answer (score 0):

Update `swagger-annotations` dependency to the latest version (currently `2.2.8`).

`groupId` has been changed from `io.swagger` to `io.swagger.core.v3`

##### Maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.8</version>
</dependency>
```

##### Gradle

```
implementation 'io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations:2.2.8'
```

Comment: Still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The problem went away after upgrading to springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui 2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Due to official document, [springdoc.org/#why-my-parameter-is-marked-as-required](https://springdoc.org/#why-my-parameter-is-marked-as-required). It's look like there are no way to prevent appearing "required".

However, I found the way. It's simple. **Just use 2 annotations with required=false**

i.e)
`@RequestParam(required = false) @Parameter(requried = false) Double latitude`

hope this will work!